# How do I use Netbeans IDE 6.9.1 to deploy to an existing instance of Glass fish 3

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

The short version of the problem is that I can't deploy projects in Netbeans, I get something like this:

Starting GlassFish Server 3
GlassFish Server 3 Server cannot start. Port is occupied.
In-place deployment at C:\Path\AppName\build\web
Initializing...
deploy?path=C:\Path\AppName\build\web&name=JSPApplication&force=true failed. Instance is not GlassFish Server 3.
C:\Path\AppName\nbproject\build-impl.xml:683: The module has not been deployed.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

However this is on a Windows 7 machine that has Glassfish 3 running on port 8080 already.

I'm sure its some ignorance on how to USE Netbeans, but I'd appreciate any help as I can't seem to find much information regarding my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetBeans comes with an integrated version of Glassfish and by default it tries to deploy web applications on this server instance.

You can configure the server instances in the `Services` tab. Right-click on `Servers` and choose `Add Server`. Now you can add your existing Glassfish instance. This should be pretty straight forward.

When you have configured NetBeans with your existing Glassfish instance, you have the change the server instance which is used for the deployment of your application. Right-click on your project and choose `Properties`. In the `Run` sub menu you can choose the server instance. Now you should be able to deploy your application on the existing Glassfish instance.

Comment: You are a lifesaver.  It's a simple thing, but you probably saved me a lot of trouble.